# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT error due to case statement in order by clause

Tags: sql-server

I have added order by columns in select, and then an error occurs

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT due to the case statement in order by clause

This is for SQL Server 2012

```
DECLARE @SortType VARCHAR(20) = 'lUf'

SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS Count,      
    nm.NoteID, nm.Title, 
    Description, CreatedDate, Createddatetime, 
    nm.BusinessID, CreatedUser, nm.LastUpdatedDatetime 
FROM
    PLO.NotesMaster nm with(nolock) 
LEFT JOIN
    PLO.NoteTags nt ON nm.NoteID = nt.NoteID
WHERE 
    (nm.Title LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%'  OR COALESCE(@keyword ,'')='')
    AND (nt.TagID = @TagID OR COALESCE(@TagID, '') = '')
    AND (nm.BusinessID = @BusinessID)
    AND (nm.CreatedUser = @UserID)
    AND (nm.Status != 2)
ORDER BY
    Pinned DESC,
    (CASE @SortType
        WHEN 'lUf' THEN nm.LastUpdatedDatetime
     END) DESC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'lul' THEN nm.LastUpdatedDatetime
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'az' THEN nm.Title  
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'za' THEN nm.Title 
     END) desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used `Select DISTINCT` and `Order by` with `Case` statement, you need to include all order by columns with case statement into your select statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(*) OVER () AS Count,      
    nm.NoteID, nm.Title, 
    Description, CreatedDate, Createddatetime, 
    nm.BusinessID, CreatedUser, nm.LastUpdatedDatetime,
    Pinned DESC,
    (CASE @SortType
        WHEN 'lUf' THEN nm.LastUpdatedDatetime
     END) DESC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'lul' THEN nm.LastUpdatedDatetime
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'az' THEN nm.Title  
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'za' THEN nm.Title 
     END) desc
FROM
    PLO.NotesMaster nm with(nolock) 
LEFT JOIN
    PLO.NoteTags nt ON nm.NoteID = nt.NoteID
WHERE 
    (nm.Title LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%'  OR COALESCE(@keyword ,'')='')
    AND (nt.TagID = @TagID OR COALESCE(@TagID, '') = '')
    AND (nm.BusinessID = @BusinessID)
    AND (nm.CreatedUser = @UserID)
    AND (nm.Status != 2)
ORDER BY
    Pinned DESC,
    (CASE @SortType
        WHEN 'lUf' THEN nm.LastUpdatedDatetime
     END) DESC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'lul' THEN nm.LastUpdatedDatetime
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'az' THEN nm.Title  
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'za' THEN nm.Title 
     END) desc
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS Count,      
        nm.NoteID, nm.Title, 
        Description, CreatedDate, Createddatetime, 
        nm.BusinessID, CreatedUser, nm.LastUpdatedDatetime 
    FROM
        PLO.NotesMaster nm with(nolock) 
    LEFT JOIN
        PLO.NoteTags nt ON nm.NoteID = nt.NoteID
    WHERE 
        (nm.Title LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%'  OR COALESCE(@keyword ,'')='')
        AND (nt.TagID = @TagID OR COALESCE(@TagID, '') = '')
        AND (nm.BusinessID = @BusinessID)
        AND (nm.CreatedUser = @UserID)
        AND (nm.Status != 2)
) t
ORDER BY
    Pinned DESC,
    (CASE @SortType
        WHEN 'lUf' THEN nm.LastUpdatedDatetime
     END) DESC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'lul' THEN nm.LastUpdatedDatetime
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'az' THEN nm.Title  
     END) ASC,
    (CASE @SortType 
        WHEN 'za' THEN nm.Title 
     END) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have not:

> I have added order by columns in select, and then an error occurs

For example, you have not added the following columns:

```
CreatedUser BusinessID Description NoteID Createddatetime CreatedDate
```

You can start commenting the columns in the `SELECT` to see when the query starts working.

Comment: I using only 3 columns for order by clause.ie pinned,lastupdateddatetime and title.I have added these 3 columns

Comment: @alenantony you need to add all of them - all columns referred in the SELECT statement must be specified in the `ORDER BY` clause - just add them after current columns, they will do no harm.